# If $A, B \in M_n$ be positive definite and $detA \circ B ) = det(AB)$ then $A$ and $B$ are positive diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n$ be positive definite.We define $A \circ B = [{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}]$.

Suppose  $detA \circ B ) = det(AB)$.

Why are $A$ and $B$ positive diagonal matrices?

Comment: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379573900232/1-s2.0-0024379573900232-main.pdf?_tid=9859ee36-8db5-11e5-837c-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1447824859_29834aa4c59d9bbac543e22c8960713c

I did some scouring and found a paper that contains the proof. Look at Corollary 3.7. There are a number of intermediate results though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadamard's inequality states that $\det A\le\prod_{i=1}^na_{ii}$ when $A\succeq0$ and in case $A\succ0$, equality holds iff $A$ is diagonal. Oppenheim's inequality states that $(\det A)\prod_{i=1}^nb_{ii}\le\det A\circ B$ when $A,B\succeq0$. Combining the two, the result immediately follows.